# Restoring VPN profile from Wireguard from old system data

Tags: windows, vpn, reinstall

Recently I had to reinstall Windows 11 due to the problems I had with the machine on which I was using Wireguard VPN. I had a profile working but I haven't created a copy of the profile with the private key I used for the connection.

I did a system backup before formatting, so I can restore it from there but the thing is that I don't really know where Wireguard stores the profile. I did some reasearch and found [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/ckjp71/wireguards_configuration_file_is_missing_after/) where someone mentioned location `C:\Windows.old\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\WireGuard\Configurations`. However, this folder did not exist in the new system, the aforementioned folder contained a folder Data which I've found in `%programfiles%\Wireguard`.

Are there any other ways to get the data back without restoring the backup just for this profile and recreating the private key?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to locate the WireGuard config data on my system.

[This post](https://www.ericlight.com/wireguard-on-windows-part-2.html) suggests that the data is stored in a system-encrypted area called "DPAPI" that requires a special API to access it. I don't know what that is, but to me it sounds pretty inaccessible, especially after the system can't boot anymore. It's probably not worth the effort and rather go find the source of it again than to extract it from a dead system.